git: untracked files not being ignored
So, i'm doing a little project with rust and i would also like to use git in order to learn both in a more practical way. The problem started when i created gitignore, because in rust, both the "target/" folder and "Cargo.Lock" need to be ignored, but when i added those files to gitignore, it was still showing those files as untracked files in the status and they could still be added and commited which is not what its supposed to happen, heres some screenshots:


Also, heres the file tree, the repository is located in the "game" folder.

So, i saw some videos, those files weren't even supposed to be in there the moment i created gitignore. Some sources that i read on were just showing how to ignore files that were already added to the repo using rm --cached, but of course i cant do that since those files arent even being tracked.
I already tried:

deleting the repo and creating a new one
adding these untracked files to the repo and then removing them with rm --cached
changing the names of those files, like "/target/" or just "target"

This is an example of one the videos that i saw, the moment he created and added those 3 files to gitignore, they weren't even in the untracked files, even before commiting gitignore


“those files weren't even supposed to be in there the moment i created gitignore” – that doesn’t matter. As long as they’re untracked, ignores will still apply. Also, target/ needs to be ignored, yes, but Cargo.lock should not be ignored. Are your .gitignore lines indented? I can’t tell. (Plain text is better than a screenshot.)

Oh hi, sorry for not posting in text, i'm still learning this platform. I checked here and the lines seem to be fine, no spaces or anything, now, the screenshot did showed the first line there with nothing and i thought that was it but even after fixing it, problem still persists. Also i don't know about this cargo.lock information, the gitignore repo from github (created by wirecat) did suggested ignoring it in case of creating an executable.

I see, but I would say it’s bad advice, and doesn’t seem to be supported by the page it links to. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-have-cargolock-in-version-control

From the same terminal where you’re running git status, what does cat -v .gitignore show? And git check-ignore -v target?

I'm guessing  this is a dup: git is showing changes in files that are already added to gitignore?

re: Cargo.lock they got it the wrong way around. Libraries usually don't need to check it into version control but executables should.

Both libraries and executables should check it into version control, you just have to be aware of the thing the Rust book says (the lockfile isn’t representative of all versions your library could be installed with).

Oh hi, so yeah my bad i did read the whole cargo thing wrong, my bad. Also, i have also solved the issue by just restarting from scratch, deleted the folder, created a new one and ran cargo. what i seem to have failed to realized is that cargo already started a new repo the moment you create a new project, i didnt saw it because i forgot to toggle hidden folders beforehand, its a new pc and those are off by default
